Unexpected error on a route on Next js project src/app router only on server
The problem Im facing is that neither on development nor on production,when Im on local, i get no error on the route of /blog/page.jsx . The moment i check the same page on the deployed version i see this on my page :
Application error: a client-side exception has occurred (see the browser console for more information).
"use server";

import React from "react";
import LatestBlog from "@/src/components/blog/LatestBlog";

const BlogArchive = async () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <LatestBlog />
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogArchive;



"use client";

import React from "react";

const LatestBlog = () => {
  return <section className={"container"}></section>;
};

export default LatestBlog;

After hours of debugging I found out that when the page is empty of imports from external components in the return for rendering, it works fine and i can even show the data im fetching, but the moment i import a component i get an error. even though the component im importing only contains a static h1 tag still i get this error, also even the line for importing is enough to make the project return an error on that specific route.
how can i prevent this and how am i supposed to find the error when no error is being shown on my server log as well ?

Update the question to include what is in the browser console.

Try removing the 'use server'
Because every page in app router by default is server rendered.
'use server' is used when we use server actions!

I already tested that, removed it from the page and still giving me the same thing
